# Good lightweighted Continous integration tool to use with github?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I am developing a small python web service with bunch of analytical codes and searching for a lightweighted, easy-use but all-around Continuous Integration tool to use together with github.

I push my code onto github and hope that by every pushing continuous integration can run tests and check the integreity

some recommended tools from github website https://github.com/integrations
like cloudBees, circleci etc.

Which kinds of CI tools is best for me at this moment ? thanks a lot

And would be kind if you could give some tips/good tutorials on coutinuous workflow(development and deployment) with github and docker

Comment: This is a hard question to answer, because there is no right answer. You really can't go wrong with any of the popular services (CircleCI, TravisCI, etc.) and they are easy to set up. They all kind of do the same thing. The best way to figure out what you like is to just start trying them.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jake said I would say that a cloud based tool like [SnapCI](https://snap-ci.com/), Circle or Travis would work well for you as you are already hosting your source in the cloud. If you are working on a public repo many of these tools are free.

In order to help with Docker and Github you'd need to be more specific about your needs.